# Get result after an update query

Tags: java, postgresql, rx-java

I am making the following query which works and updates the info into the database as expected. But is there a way I can get an output from Single < UpdateResult >?

```
public Single<UpdateResult> update(UpdateEventRequest request) {
    return client.rxUpdateWithParams(
            "UPDATE mydb.sample SET sta_cd=?, some_ts=current_timestamp WHERE id=? RETURNING sta_cd",
            new JsonArray(Arrays.asList(sta_cd, id)));
}
```

From the following e variable, I was hoping to get the value "10012". But it doesn't seem possible. Tried with map, flatmap and just see options available in e. The only result data in e is 'keys' which is an empty list and 'updated' which is an integer value of 1. My DB is postgres and was expecting results from from Single < UpdateResult > since am using 'RETURNING' in the query.

I have done the same for an insert operation which works but that is via the method rxQueryWithParams() and that returns a Single < ResultSet > instead. Thus wondering if this is even possible. Been having a look at docs and maybe this is not possible as an update query is returning a Single < UpdateResult > . Looking for advice if this is possible, to return data from an update query or a way around this. Please advice. Thanks.

```
    Single<UpdateResult> result = someClass.update("10012", "78632");

    result.subscribe(
            e -> {
                System.out.println("success: " + e); // I land here as expected
            },
            error -> {
                System.out.println("error: " + error);
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `RETURNING` in these commands, treat these `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands as queries.

Run them through `rxQueryWithParams()` so you can retrieve the results.

When you run `rxUpdateWithParams()`, the [`UpdateResult`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/sql/UpdateResult.html) contains only the number of rows affected.